# CONVERT function in SQL Server with int datatype for Date functions

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to print to print today's date in VARCHAR format it prints well but when I tried to print the same date in int it shows 43004. I know that we can't print date in integer format but what is the significance of that number 43004.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, GETDATE(), 110);
```

Output: 43004

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 110);
```

Output: 09-27-2017

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the number of days since `1900-01-01`

Comment: `select dateadd(day,43004,'19000101')`

Comment: That is the number of days since 1/1/1900 the day you ran this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert INT to DATETIME (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not the same thing at all as this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivia suitable for a pub quiz, not a *practical* problem to be solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting 0 as DATE and DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643454/casting-0-as-date-and-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it's the number days since `1901-01-01`.

You can see this by running:

```
select dateadd(day,43004,'19000101')
```

Another way to get the same result, is:

`select datediff(day,getdate(),0)`

In the query above, 0 is `'1900-01-01'` represented as an `INT`. You'll commonly see similar methods for finding the first day of the current month.

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to see the output of the query

```
select cast(0 as datetime)
, getdate(),
cast(getdate() as int)
```

output

```
01.01.1900 00:00:00     27.09.2017 16:09:25    43004
```

So 0 is the value of `1.1.1900` which is the lowest value of date time allowed and every single day after it gets a number after 0 so 1 is `02.01.1900 00:00:00`