# Convert the date functions code to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is sql server code, I have to convert this where condition to snowflake code, can I know how do we convert this into snowflake code and also I need explanation please.

```
where CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 19000000+datecolumn))  >= cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -1 , 0),120) as date)

and CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 19000000+datecolumn))  <=  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1),120) as date)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issue(s) you encountered?

Comment: Also `snowflake-schema` tag is irrelevant for your question

Comment: Ideally, if you provide us the format of what is in datecolumn, it'd be very helpful.  Snowflake does not require so much converting, but still need to know what the datecolumn values are in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

so the left side is the same for both `CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 19000000+datecolumn))`

so the outer most layer is a convertion to date which is snow falk can also be done via `::date` and is side of that there is a conversion of a number to a 8 character string  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 19000000+datecolumn)` which is in a format that can be considered a date, and has the input as `19000000` + `datecolumn` so I would guess you date format is `YYYYMMDD` and `datecolumn` is `YYMMDD` since 1900. Which in snowflake would use the explicit form of [TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html)

`TO_DATE( ( 19000000 + datecolumn )::text, 'YYYYMMDD')`

both the right hand sides are also comparing to dates, thus the outer `CAST(... as date)` which is the same as the ::text for I use above, see [CAST](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/cast.html)

so the inner most part is `DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())` which is the number of months since beginning of time in your DB timeframe, and the current date in months, with 1 is subtracted from, and that many months are added since 0 in DB timeframe, thus `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,  0, GETDATE()) -1,  0)` is the begin of the prior month. As today is December 22nd (if we pretend this year is year 0 in DB time) we are in month 12 which we minus 1 from thus add 11 months to 0 we get the date 2019-11-01, now 0 seems to be '1900-01-01' accord to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643454/casting-0-as-date-and-datetime), and I am going to guess the numeric value is whole days (as it's seems to be Microsoft's style), which would make the `-1` start be the year '1899-12-31' and thus while we are finding one month month of time due to the date being a month prior, the date we are starting from is the end of the month, thus the second statement appears to be "end of the prior month" but I am not sure how SQL Server handles in the prior month was Feb, and thus if the end date is truncated to end of Feb, or if you end up 31 days after the start of the 1st of Feb.

Ether way that date is then turned to a `text` and then converted to `date`

It would again make more sense to just get the `CURRENT_DATE()`, truncate that to the month, and then step backward. And if you want the end of the prior month truncate and step back a day, or if you want 31 days, step forward that amount.

Thus

```
dateadd(month, -1, date_trunc('month', current_date())) as first_day_of_prior_month
dateadd(day, -1, date_trunc('month', current_date())) as last_day_of_prior_month
```

which is actually what the snowflake [date-time help](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-examples.html#calculating-business-calendar-dates-and-times) suggests